# How to compile libtiff in C++ Builder?

Tags: c++builder, libtiff

I want to use libtiff in C++ Builder. I need to compile it, because distributed Windows binaries don't work with C++ Builder. How do I compile libtiff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libtiff version 4.5.1 supports CMake, but I faced some compile errors with C++ Builder 10.3.3. Therefore I created a project file manually.

First, create some header files with CMake: [Follow the documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_CMake_with_C%2B%2B_Builder) on how to use CMake with C++ Builder.

Run command `cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=bcc32c.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=bcc32c.exe -G Ninja .` This generates following files: *libtiff\tif_config.h*, *libtiff\tiffconf.h*, and *port\libport_config.h*. You could also create them manually.

Compiling the project:

1. Create new project with type "Static library", and name it "libtiff"
2. Add all C files from *libtiff* and *port* directories to the project, except *tif_unix.c* and *mkspans.c*
3. Compile

Files you need for your project:

- libtiff.lib
- All header files from libtiff directory